# Reset admin password in Sitecore 5.3?

Tags: sitecore

I need to reset the admin password in a Sitecore 5.3 installation - any ideas how i can do this? Currently i have no access to the backend, as the password has been changed, but no one remembers to what.

There is no info in the security db that can not be overwritten, so any options are open. I have direct access to the database (SQL).

Comment: I have no idea what 5.3 structure looks like, but I use this code to do it in 6.2.  Perhaps it is useful?  perhaps it is not.   System.Web.Security.MembershipUser user = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(@"sitecore\Admin");
            if (user != null)
            {
                string pw = user.ResetPassword();

Comment: No luck, but thx for the suggestion :)

Comment: I suggest opening up a Sitecore support request.  They can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an instance of 5.3 running so I don't know if this will fully work for 5.3 but here's my suggestion.

One thing you could try is copying the values of the **Passowrd** and **PasswordSalt** field of the **aspnet_Membership** table in the **Core** database for a user whose password you know and pasting those values into the respective fields for the **admin** user.

The **aspnet_Membership** table stores only the ID of the admin user.  To get the ID of your admin user you need to query the **aspnet_Users** table for username **admin**.  Get the ID of the admin user in the aspnet_Users table, then query the aspnet_Membership table for that ID, update the Password and PasswordSalt fields with the values from another user whose password you know and try logging in again with that user's password.

Comment: There is no such table in the Core database. V 5.3 and V6 does not have the same security structure. Does v53 use apnet_Memebership?

Comment: This only applies to v6.  In v5.3, users are stored as Sitecore items.  You might be able to use a similar strategy though.

Answer (score 1):

To reset the 'admin' password and change it to 'b'. It is very simple just execute the provided SQL script on the core database:

```sql
UPDATE [aspnet_Membership] SET Password='qOvF8m8F2IcWMvfOBjJYHmfLABc=' 
WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM [aspnet_Users] WHERE UserName = 'sitecore\Admin')
```

Answer (score 0):

WARNING (Sitecore 6.x)!

After executing following script (thanks to Harsh Baid)

```
UPDATE [aspnet_Membership] SET Password='qOvF8m8F2IcWMvfOBjJYHmfLABc=' 
WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM [aspnet_Users] WHERE UserName = 'sitecore\Admin')
```

don't forget to execute the similar script for salt:

```
UPDATE [aspnet_Membership] SET PasswordSalt='OM5gu45RQuJ76itRvkSPFw==' 
WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM [aspnet_Users] WHERE UserName = 'sitecore\Admin')
```

And for user approve

```
UPDATE [aspnet_Membership] SET IsApproved=1 
WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM [aspnet_Users] WHERE UserName = 'sitecore\Admin')
```